# simple codes in assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I am new to assembly language using the Raspberry Pi. I tried to run this simple program on a Raspberry Pi 3(ARM 8086). It does not cause an error but when I try to see the result in a terminal after compiling and running `as _o example.o example.s`, `gcc _o example examle.s` and `./example`. the execution result is segmentation fault, can you help me please?

```
.align 2
    .text
    .global main
main:
    stmfd r13!, {r14}

    mov r0,#1
    bl print

    mov r0,#2
    bl print

    mov r0,#3
    bl print

    ldmfd r13!,{pc} @ return to OS

print:
    stmfd r13!, {r0-r3,r12,r14}
    mov r1,r0
    ldr r0, =num_str
    bl printf
    ldmfd r13!, {r0-r3,r12,pc}

.data

    .align 2
num_str:
    .asciz “%d\n”
.end
```

Comment: _"8086"_ Huh? Also, you've got a bunch of typos in the commands you say you use (`_o`, `examle.s`, `first` which doesn't match `example`).

Comment: @Michael you are right thank you so much for noticing that , it l have changed it to example, the result is segmentation fault.

Comment: This code works just fine for me, provided the `“”` quotes are replaced with syntactically-correct `""` ones - I assume those are just an artefact of the posting here and not in your actual code, because they make the assembler throw an error which you say doesn't happen.

Comment: l changed it and l got the same error.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ABI requires that the stack pointer is aligned to multiple of 8 bytes, your `main` function decrements the stack pointer by 4 making it unaligned. 
Presumably `printf` uses an instruction that requires 8 byte alignment.